# django rest Error - AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Tags: python, django, linux, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I'm build Django app, and it's work fine on my machine, but when I run inside docker container it's rest framework keep crashing, but when I comment any connection with rest framework it's work fine.

- My machine: Kali Linux 2021.3
- docker machine: Raspberry Pi 4 4gb
- docker container image: python:rc-alpine3.14
- python version on my machine: Python 3.9.7
- python version on container: Python 3.10.0rc2

error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 55, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 728, in run_tests
    self.run_checks(databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 665, in run_checks
    call_command('check', verbosity=self.verbosity, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 181, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/check.py", line 63, in handle
    self.check(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/project/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    path("", include("apps.urls", namespace="apps")),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/apps/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import api
  File "/app/apps/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .serializers import *
  File "/app/apps/serializers.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rest_framework import serializers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 27, in <module>
    from rest_framework.compat import postgres_fields
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/compat.py", line 59, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:rc-alpine3.14

COPY . /app 
WORKDIR /app

ENV UWSGI_PROFILE=core
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
RUN apk add --update --no-cache g++ gcc libxslt-dev # add some nessery libs
RUN apk add python3-dev build-base linux-headers pcre-dev
RUN pip3 install -U pip # upgrade pip
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg \
    && pip install Pillow \
    && apk del build-deps


RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies wget ca-certificates && \
    wget "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -O /dev/stdout | python


RUN pip install uwsgi

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt # install all requirements
RUN python uploadstatics.py

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["gunicorn","project.wsgi:application", "-b 0.0.0.0:8060"]
```

NOTES:

- I use gunicorn to run the app (the error show even I run't from manage.py)

Comment: You are using python 3.10, which removes that, use python 3.9 instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can downgrade your Python version. That should solve your problem; if not, use `collections.abc.Mapping` instead of the deprecated `collections.Mapping`.

Refer here: [Link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/pull/419)

Answer (score 5):

In your docker file you set the image as `python:rc-alpine3.14` which uses python 3.10. Considering that 3.10 is very recently released, many of the packages are yet to upgrade and depending on the version constraints you have in your `requirements.txt` that might also cause incompatible versions. The problem here is Django Rest framework uses the requests package which is using `collections.MutableMapping`, if I write this in python 3.9 I get the following warning which says this will be removed in 3.10, hence you should downgrade for now to python 3.9:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1
DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
```

Another thing about writing `python:rc-alpine3.14` as the image is just asking for your code to break! Specify a specific stable and released version rather than the release candidate `rc`:

```
FROM python:3.9.7-alpine3.14

...
```