# module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Tags: django, docker

I am trying to upload images from admin page to the data base in django project that I have configured and I have tried many ways to fix this but does not worked
Anybody please guide me

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR / 'media')
```

**urls.py**

```
 urlpatters[...] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
    product_img = models.ImageField('Product Image', upload_to = 'product_img', blank=True  )
```

**docker file**

```
FROM python:3.9.7-alpine3.14

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirement.txt /app/
RUN pip3 install -r requirement.txt

COPY . /app/
```

**requirments.txt**

```
Django==3.2.9
Pillow==2.2.1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django rest Error - AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69464512/django-rest-error-attributeerror-module-collections-has-no-attribute-mutab)

Comment: its not working out for me.

Comment: Is it correct ``product_img = models.ImageField('Product Image', upload_to = 'product_img', blank=True  )`` ? I think it should be like this ``product_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'product_img', blank=True  )``